# Python 2.7.6 and multiprocessing "leaks memory"

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I'm running the following code on 64-bit Xubuntu 14.04 LTS and Python 2.7.6

```
import numpy
import multiprocessing

def f(i):
    result = numpy.zeros((224, 244, 3), dtype='float32')
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Start...'

    for i in xrange(100):

        print 'Attempt:', i

        args = [0] * 1000
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
        v = pool.map(f, args)

        print 'Pool done.'

        import gc
        gc.collect()
        del v
        v = None

        print 'Clean done.'
```

Surprisingly it consume all 16 Gb I have on my machine in few iterations. It totally froze the system. As far as I understand - this should not happen, because "v" is local resource and it can be deallocated.

So why this "memory leak" actually happen?

multiprocessing version is 0.70a1, numpy - 1.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `pool.close()` in the cleaning section is enough to fix the memory leak without the need to resort to the garbage collector explicitly. As for why it happens, I have no idea, but it surely depends on [how the pool is implemented](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l138) (most likely it keeps a reference of the result somewhere)

Comment: To add to that: Looks like it's not `v` that's the problem, but the pool itself. It's `Pool.__init__()` pushes `self` into quite a few subobjects, including background threads. So `pool` doesn't get cleaned up directly via reference counting. The pool is also a weird object from the perspective of the GC: Its local memory footprint is relatively small, but the attached subprocesses are heavy on the system. The GC in the main process, however, rarely runs, because there is little memory pressure on the main process. You are only creating few objects (locally) in each loop.